# Setting a drupal view to a random page number

Tags: drupal, drupal-views

I have views 2 installed and I have created a view that is displayed in the front page.

The view displays some page links ( 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | ... etc). I want to know if it's possible to make the view start at a random page instead of always starting at page 1.

Note: I don't want to randomize the display I really just want to randomize the page it loads.

Thanks

**Possible Solution:**

In the views_pre_execute hook I used this:

```
$view->query->pager->set_current_page([random value]);
```

I am not sure I can determine the number of total pages in the pager at this time but I am going to keep investigating (The $view object given in the hook has tons of properties with arrays and other objects which makes this complicated)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I do not know how to do this from the Views UI, but you should be able to achieve this using one of [the views module hooks](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/group/views_hooks/6), in this case probably [`hook_views_pre_execute`](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/function/hook_views_pre_execute/6). Unfortunately, the documentation for these is practically non existing, so you'd need to implement the hook in a custom module and inspect the passed in view object via the debugger (or print, var_dump, etc. statements).

You should look for `$view->pager['current_page']`, which you can set to a random page. Unfortunately, if I read the code correctly, the count query that determines the possible number of pages is not yet run at this point, so you'll either have to use a 'best guess', or come up with a different way to determine the proper range to select from...

NOTE: This is in no way meant as an 'authoritative' answer - just a pointer where I'd start looking, since nobody else has answered this so far. I might well be missing a more obvious/easy solution :/

Comment: Hey! I used the view_pre_execute hook and used this: $view->query->pager->set_current_page(<random value>); I set it to random using the range I know the view will have. I am not sure I can get the exact number of pages in the view. Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 2):

Another option would be to randomize the entries in your views. So your page would always be page 1 but it achieves your objective of seeing something different every time come on your site.

In your sort criteria (in the Global Group) add 
Global: Random -- Randomize the display order.

(Inspired by suggestion at http://mydrupal.com/random_node_or_front_page_in_drupal_like_stumbleupon )

Comment: I did know this one, but I really just want to randomize the selected page view and not the view itself

Comment: +1 for a good alternative (even if it did not match the OPs exact requirements - could as well have ;)

Answer (score 1):

I have just created a custom pager that goes automatically to last page and I think it is related to what your are trying to do :

In project.info :

```
files[] = plugins/views_plugin_pager_last.inc
```

In project.module :

```
function cvoxm_views_plugins(){
  return array(
    'pager' => array(
      'last' => array(
        'title' => t('Paged output, full pager and last by default'),
        'short title' => t('Full & Last'),
        'help' => t('Paged output, full Drupal style and last by default'),
        'handler' => 'views_plugin_pager_last',
        'help topic' => 'pager-last',
        'uses options' => TRUE,
      ),
    )
  );
}
```

And the content of plugins/views_plugin_pager_last.inc is :

```
class views_plugin_pager_last extends views_plugin_pager_full {

  function pre_execute(&$query) {
    if(!isset($_GET['page'])){ // TODO: Should use pager_id
      // Go to last page
      $this->set_current_page($this->get_total_items() / $this->get_items_per_page() - 1 );
      $this->query(); // Rebuild query
      $this->update_page_info(); // Update info
    }
  }
}
```